# Azure search - Indexing many-to-many

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

I need to crawl data from multiple tables into single search index, problem though is that some of the needed data are from tables with no direct relation (e.g., any relationship in DB that is not one-to-one, provided example bellow of approx look of the DB). Views are not an option as their crawls timeouts (because of forced order by condition) and I can't change table structures, is there any other way without creating table with flattened duplicated data to propagate index?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no other way; you need to denormalize and flatten the data in order to index into Azure search.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the SQL Indexer since you can't use views and the SQL Indexer doesn't know how to deal with joins. You can index [using the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) or [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.documentsoperationsextensions.indexasync?view=azure-dotnet), but you will need to reconcile your DB schema with your index schema.

For production applications using Azure Search, we recommend flattening the data as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types). Assuming each document in your index represents an instance of entity X, this will involve duplicating the Users that are related to more than one X.

Another potential option is to use [Complex Types](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6670910-modelling-complex-types-in-indexes), which is currently in private preview. That will allow you to model one-to-many relationships more naturally, as long as the cardinalities aren't too extreme. For example, if each X has hundreds, but not thousands, of Users, Complex Types might be a good fit. It would still require duplicating Users due to the many-to-many relationship, however. If you're interested in evaluating Complex Types, please see [this User Voice post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6670910-modelling-complex-types-in-indexes) for instructions on how to join the private preview.