# How to join two or more tables in Azure Cognitive search?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I have been using the Azure Cognitive Search to create the indexes for two or more tables and using the API in .Net code to retrieve the values from the tables.

Now I am trying to join two or more tables as a single index and use that index in the code.

I know how to create different indexes for different tables separately. Now I want to know how to join two or more tables in Azure Cognitive Search.

Is there any way to join the tables in Azure Cognitive Search? If it is possible please, let me know how to do it.

Comment: I don't think there is a possibility to join indexes in queries. You'll need to rethink the approach I think. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I a trying to join two or more tables while creating the index in azure cognitive search.

Comment: Ok so you have tables A and B and you'd like to put data from them into one index in Search?

Comment: Yes, I have two tables A and B in different database which is on the same server and I am trying to put the data from them into one index in search

Comment: Could it be possible for you to make a view in SQL that combines the data you want? You can set a view as the source for the indexer.

Comment: I can create the view in SQL that combines the data but I don't know how to set a view as the source for the indexer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join data in Azure Cognitive Search. It's a common question and there are some good answers on this already. Ref.:

[Search data in multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69664401/search-data-in-multiple-tables)

and

[Azure search - Indexing many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058360/azure-search-indexing-many-to-many/53072485#53072485)

A common solution is to flatten the data by joining it on index time. There are several ways to join the data as part of indexing.

1. Implement your own content processing logic that compiles data before submitting to the index. This approach is best if you use the SDK to submit data.
2. Implement custom skillsets that merge data. If you are using a built-in indexer, skillsets is usually the way to go.
3. Join the data in a view and then index that view instead of each table independently.

Flattening data so that the records you index resemble the records you expect back from search is a common technique used in search implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Dan's answer.

Join is not supported in Azure Cognitive Search for index results.

If your requirement fits, you may try joining the data source tables contents before having them indexed and use a single index that has the joined results.

Table joining is not relevant pattern for Search Analytics solutions even in the cases that it is supported, typically it is not  efficient.

Followed-up from your [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1161087/how-to-join-two-or-more-tables-in-azure-cognitive) thread.